# Showing Terms and Conditions in an iPad App

Tags: ios, ipad

My customer wants to show a Terms & Conditions pop-over when someone uses the iPad App for the first time. I have done it but just want to make sure that I'm not breaking the Apple guidelines.

Is it acceptable if the App open up a Terms& Conditions popup once and ask the user to accept it to access the resources?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A better place for this would be the custom EULA you can provide when submitting your App for review.

Comment: Yea, EULA would be the right place. But Sid, Can I use the pop over method if the customer insists for this, does it break the guidelines in someway ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider End User Licence Agreement. This is for the applications on app store which require the 'Terms and Conditions Agreement' for the app. Here is a beautiful post about  this.

http://peninsulawyer.com/blog/2011/8/23/app-developers-dont-sweat-the-small-print.html

I think it should serve your purpose

Comment: Yea, EULA would be the right place. But is there any chance for rejection if the customer insists for this ?

Comment: What's your scenario if they reject the popover? Terminate the app? That might go against guidelines. 
Given Apple provide the App store EULA option I can imagine that they would reject you for killing the app if the user says no.

Comment: Freney - Thanks for the response. I thought of directing the user to a message screen which prints he has to accept the T&C to proceed. We do not terminate the App but the user can't proceed with the App then.

Comment: Hi All , Thanks for your help on this. I am asked to continue with the T&C popup this time. Hopefully we will move it to EULA next time. Thank you so much for your help.